# Is it somehow possible to feed a CuPy array into a Detectron model?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, cupy

I read an Image with PIL and turn it into a cupy array instead of a numpy one. Now I would like to feed this cupy array into the detectron model. Is that somehow possible?

Thanks!

Comment: The [CuPy documentation](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/interoperability.html) describes interoperability with PyTorch. Assuming the Detectron code supports PyTorch tensors as input you simply need to convert your CuPy array to a PyTorch tensor and then provide it to Detectron.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'strides'. Seems like it doesn't support PyTorch tensors.

Comment: you can use DLPack to convert CuPy ndarrays to torch tensors, there is an explanation in the link that @jodag posted above :)

Comment: I guess that wouldn't work either with detectron since I cannot provide a tensor to detectron